# Axis client side serializer/deserializer

Tags: java, serialization, apache-axis

I have an array `MyBean` sent over the wire from my server side Axis web service. I got the serialisation working on the client side by adding

```
<beanMapping qname="MyBean" xmlns:ns="myns.MyBeanService"
                 languageSpecificType="java:myns.Appartment"/>
```

Now I get `No deserializer for {myns.MyBean}MyBean` on the client side. How can I tell the client to use the default BeanSerializer and BeanDeserializer since there is no server-config.wsdd ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

([source p51](https://books.google.be/books?id=2P2F5i8v3EwC&pg=PA61&lpg=PA61&dq=axis+make+serializer&source=bl&ots=ZJbhpxPBAd&sig=WBHk58DbiR52-VeZWUE_Y4kwNeg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwie39b24sfMAhVMBsAKHaxAC2oQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=axis%20make%20serializer&f=false)) In the client side class `MyServiceSoapBindingStub`, right after

```
org.apache.axis.client.Call _call = createCall();
```

add

```
QName qn = new QName("myns.MyBeanService", "MyBean");

call.registerTypeMapping(MyBean.class, qn,
        new BeanSerializerFactory(cl, qn),
        new BeanDeserializerFactory(cl, qn));
```

This requires the client having a copy of `MyBean.java`.

Also, if `MyBean` has sub beans, the same code should be added for all sub beans. It is handy to define a utils class like this:

```
public final class WSUtils {

    public static void handleSerialization(Call call, String ns, String bean, Class cl) {

        QName qn = new QName(ns, bean);

        call.registerTypeMapping(cl, qn,
                new BeanSerializerFactory(cl, qn),
                new BeanDeserializerFactory(cl, qn));
    }
}
```

that can be used after the `createCall()` like this:

```
WSUtils.handleSerialization(_call, "myns.MyBeanService", "MyBean", MyBean.class);
```

and for sub beans:

```
WSUtils.handleSerialization(_call, "myns.MyBeanService", "MySubBean", MySubBean.class);
```